# Cutting off decimals in Year conversion in Crystal Syntax

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm printing the following year as a string in a report but it prints as 2,018.00.  How do I have it print as a four digit year string without decimals or the comma? The Truncate() didn't seem to work.

```
CStr (Year({Date}) + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either omit the `CStr`-function and set the number format on the formatting tab or, if the formula needs to return a string, you can use the arguments of the `CStr`- or `ToText`-function (which are equivalent).

Either set the second argument to define the number format:

```
CStr(Year({Date}) + 1, "####")
```

**Or**

Set the second and third argument to set the number of decimals to `0` and an empty string as thousands separator:

```
CStr(Year({Date}) + 1, 0, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is the Year() function converts the data into a Number, complete with thousands separator, decimal, and 2 significant digits after the decimal.

To get around this what I have found that works is to remove the CStr() function from your formula.  This allows you to access the Formatting tab for a Number data type by right clicking the field and selecting Format Field.  Then from the Number tab you can set the Style of the field to one of the styles that doesn't use a separator or decimal in the display.

If you are needing to concatenate this value with another string, then you can get a little more creative and use the LEFT() and REPLACE() functions like this.

```
Left(Replace(Cstr(Year({Date}) + 1), ",", ""), 4)
```

Comment: MatSnow has the better solution by taking advantage of the formatting options in the CStr() function.  My solution is more of a work-around.